# Body of abstract method in Python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaclass, abstract-methods

I have an abstract class, `Model`, with a few abstract methods, what should I put in the body of the methods?

1. A return

   ```
   class Model(metaclass=ABCMeta):
       @abstractmethod
       def foo(self):
           return
   ```
2. A pass

   ```
   class Model(metaclass=ABCMeta):
       @abstractmethod
       def foo(self):
           pass
   ```
3. Raising a descriptive error

   ```
   class Model(metaclass=ABCMeta):
       @abstractmethod
       def foo(self):
           raise NotImplementedError("Class {class_name} doesn't implement {func_name} function"
                                 .format(class_name=self.__class__.__name__, func_name=self.foo.__name__))
   ```

Typically I would implement method 3 and raise an error, however it looks like it would be redundant, as Python raises an error for me:

```
>>> bar = module.Model()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class Model with abstract methods foo
```

**Between the options presented, which is best practice? Or is there another way I should handle this?**

Comment: Don't forget that calling the code is possible, i.e. `super().foo()` is supported.

Comment: Duplicate of [What should I put in the body of an abstract method in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40894284/2301450).

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The best thing to put in the body of an `abstractmethod` (or `abstractproperty`) would be a docstring.

Then you don't need `pass` or `return` or `...` because a `return None` is implicitly included - and a docstring makes this construct "compile" without a `SyntaxError`:

```
from abc import abstractmethod, ABCMeta

class Model(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    @abstractmethod
    def foo(self):
        """This method foos the model."""
```

The docstring should then explain what one can expect of this method, so that users and subclassers know what is intended.

Comment: Ah, nice idea! I don't why I didn't think of this. I was about to post an answer using `pass`, but this is a much better idea for  the reasons you mentioned. +1

Comment: I object to the idea that the docstring should mainly tell sub-classes how to implement this method. First and foremost it should tell the caller what the function does. Any words addressed at implementeres should at most be an after-thought in the docstring

Comment: @Neuron-FreedomforUkraine I never said that it should tell **how** to it should be implemented - only what "should be implemented here". I'll see if I can clarify the example and text.