# Python’s empty function does not require a pass statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I stumbled upon an interesting and unexpected feature of Python:

```
def fun():
    """Foo’s docstring"""
```

is a valid function? According to [PEP 257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/), “*A docstring is a string literal that occurs as the first statement in a module, function, class, or method definition*” meaning that the docstring itself is considered a statement?

I would have expected that at least a [`pass`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#pass-statements) statement is required here. The above example contradicts the [Python Zen](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) of “explicit is better than implicit” as `pass` states an explicit intent, and a docstring does not.

Can anybody shed some light on the intent?

Comment: What's unclear? As that quote tells you, the string is the first statement, only one statement is required by [the grammar](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html) for the function to be syntactically valid. That's *not* an empty function, in other words.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'intent'?

Comment: I’ve extended the question...

Comment: The Zen of Python doesn't tell you about the grammar. If you think a `pass` statement after the docstring makes the code clearer in intent then by all means add one, but it isn't *required* for the code to run. It would only complicate the parser to have the requirement that `suite` contains at least one statement, except in the case that it's in a `funcdef` and that first statement is a string literal, in which case it must contain at least two. *"Simple is better than complex."*

Comment: Yes, the Python parser does allow you to do some things that violate the Zen of Python, but so what?  What exactly is your question?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I understand that. I just find it odd/surprising that a _string literal_ is also considered a _statement_ when placed in a certain location, and as a consequence allows an empty function like the one above that, to me, conflicts with other required uses of `pass`.

Comment: What do you mean *"considered a statement when placed in a certain location"*? A string literal on its own is an expression, thus an expression statement. The fact that this is *also* special-cased as a docstring when such a statement is the first in a function/class/module/method doesn't change that.

Answer (score 12):

A string literal is just like any other literal. It also works if you just put in an integer:

```
def func():
    1
```

However, it doesn't work if you only use a comment:

```
def func():
    # test

# IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Even though it's also added as docstring (saved in the `__doc__` attribute) it's also a function level constant:

```
def func():
    """I'm a function"""

>>> func.__code__.co_consts
("I'm a function", None)
```

So the presence of a string literal as only content of a function doesn't change *how* the function is actually "parsed" and "compiled" itself. Well, apart from the fact that it also got a not-None `__doc__` attribute.

It's actually very handy for `abstractmethod`s (see for example ["Body of abstract method in Python"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45826761/5393381)), where you don't need an actual function body.